# AngularJs - How to use $cacheFactory with $http

Tags: angularjs, caching

**In my app.run I call MenuSvc to populate $state, and then I call the LayoutCtrl to populate the DOM's nav, presumably with the cache and avoid another call to the server.**

**1. $http:**

> ```
> /* @ngInject */
> app.factory('MenuSvc', MenuSvc);
> function MenuSvc($http, MenuSvcCache){
>     return {
>         all: function(){
>             return $http({
>                 method: 'GET',
>                 url: 'api/menu.json',
>                 cache: MenuSvcCache
>             });
>         }
>     }
> };
> MenuSvc.$inject = ['$http', 'MenuSvcCache'];
> ```

**2. $cacheFactory:**

```
/* @ngInject */
app.factory('MenuSvcCache', MenuSvcCache);
function MenuSvcCache($cacheFactory){
    return $cacheFactory('MenuSvc')
};
MenuSvcCache.$inject = ['$cacheFactory'];
```

**3. LayoutCtrl:**

> ```
> ng.module('app.Layout').controller('LayoutCtrl', LayoutCtrl);
> function LayoutCtrl($cacheFactory, $http, MenuSvc, MenuSvcCache) {
>     var layout = this;
>     layout.pageTitle = 'LayoutCtrl';
>
>     Init();
>     function Init(){
>         if (MenuSvcCache) {
>             layout.menuItems = MenuSvcCache.get();
>             console.log(MenuSvcCache);
>         } else {
>             MenuSvc.all().success(function (data) {
>                 layout.menuItems = data;
>                 console.log(MenuSvcCache);
>             })
>                 .error(function (error) {
>                     console.log('Error: ' + error.message)
>                 });
>         }
>     }
> };
>
> LayoutCtrl.$inject = ['$cacheFactory', '$http', 'MenuSvc', 'MenuSvcCache'];
> ```

**Needless to say, it is not working. Does anyone see my mistake?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I decided to make the put call from app.run and it works there (MenuSvcCache above stays the same):**

**1. app.run**

> ```
>     app.run(function ($q, $rootScope, $state, $window, MenuSvc, MenuSvcCache) {
>     MenuSvc.all().success(function (states) {
>         MenuSvcCache.put('MenuSvc', states)
>      ..........
> ```

**2. MenuSvc**

> ```
>     same as above but removed the 'cache: true'
> ```

**3. LayoutCtrl**

> ```
>         function Init(){
>         if (MenuSvcCache) {
>             layout.menuItems = MenuSvcCache.get('MenuSvc');
>             console.log(MenuSvcCache);
>         } else {
>             MenuSvc.all().success(function (data) {
>                 layout.menuItems = data;
>                 MenuSvcCache.put('MenuSvc', data)
>                 console.log(MenuSvcCache);
>             })
>                 .error(function (error) {
>                     console.log('Error: ' + error.message)
>                 });
>         }
>     }
> };
> ```

**Added bonus, if you want to use a refresh button:**

> ```
>         layout.clearCache = function () {
>         if (MenuSvcCache) {
>             MenuSvcCache.removeAll();
>         }
>     }
> ```